# When adding Dependency: "could not find or load Main Class"

Tags: java, azure, gradle, azure-cosmosdb

when I add

```
compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-cosmos', version: '4.0.1-beta.4'
```

to my dependencies in the `build.gradle` my Jar File will not execute anymore.

I basically create a new project from scratch with `gradle init` and add this dependency.

It throws an "Error: Could not find or load main class", when I run `java -jar <jarFile>`

Without the dependency, it works fine and prints the "Hello World."

What am I missing here?

My current `build.gradle` looks as follow:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmos
    compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-cosmos', version: '4.0.1-beta.4'
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Main-Class': 'gradle.cosmos.example.App'
        )
    }
}
```

App Class looks as follow:

```java
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package gradle.cosmos.example;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello world.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: All I got is `Error: Could not find or load main class gradle.cosmos.example.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gradle.cosmos.example.App`, when calling the JAR File

Comment: This is the content of the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: ```Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: gradle.cosmos.example.App```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
plugins {  
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {     
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'  
    compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-cosmos', version: '4.0.1-beta.4'    
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'gradle.cosmos.example.App'
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works this way, but the needed dependency of azure-cosmos is then missing in the JAR File